# string of ints to list of ints with a TryParse

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code:

```
TheString = "443,432,546,4547,4445,2,132"; //actually, about 1000 entries    
List<int> TheListOfIDs = new List<int>();   
TheListOfLeadIDs = from string s in TheString.Split(',')
                   select Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList<int>();
```

I know I can use a try catch to make sure the conversion doesn't throw an error but I was wondering how I could make this work with a TryParse in the linq statement.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when a non int value is found, replace it with 0, ignore it, throw an error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
TheListOfLeadIDs = (from string s in TheString.Split(',')
                    let value = 0
                    where int.TryParse(s, out value)
                    select value).ToList<int>();
```

Comment: I get error: `readonly range variable cannot be used as an assignment target`

Comment: This doesn't work. 'Cannot pass the range variable as an out or ref parameter'

Comment: I'm not gonna downvote, since I might be missing something. However: This does NOT work.

Comment: hmm, might be something that changed with Roslyn (newest C# compiler)? Let me try it.

Answer (score 9):

```
TheListOfIDs = TheString.Split(',')
                        .Select(s => 
                        {
                            int i;
                            return Int32.TryParse(s, out i) ? i : -1;
                        }).ToList();
```

This will return a `-1` for any failed conversion.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this:

```
string TheString = "443,432,546,4547,4445,2,132"; //actually, about 1000 entries
int temp=0;
var TheListOfIDs= TheString
                  .Split(',')
                  .Where (ts =>int.TryParse(ts,out temp))
                  .Select (ts =>temp )
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: not tried.

```
string[] myString = TheString.Split(',');

int leadId;
var theListOfLeadIds = (from myString in myString where int.TryParse(myString, out leadId) select int.Parse(myString)).ToList<int>();
```

Meaning that you will only get value successfully parsed ...